# How to query the data under Firebase when using push during the insertion?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
-patient
  -9876543210
    -hjsfrhwugfshgjgjwwg
      -name
      -description
      -tokennumber
      -disease
      -date-'24/12/91'
    -hjsfrhwugfshgjgjwwg
      -name
      -description
      -tokennumber
      -disease
      -date-'24/12/91'
  -9876543211
```

I'm having data like this. I want to show the all child which meets conditon that date=24/12/91.`before im using push I can retrieve all child data from patient.but after using unique keys I cant retrieve.this is my previous code.

I'm having data like this. I want to show the all child which meets conditon that date=24/12/91.`before im using push I can retrieve all child data from patient.but after using unique keys I cant retrieve.this is my previous code.

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                Query query = reference.child("patient").orderByChild("dates").equalTo(date);
                query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {

                    public ArrayList<HashMap> hashMap;
                    public HashMap<String, String> hash;




                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                            medical_list = new ArrayList<>();

                            for (DataSnapshot patient : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                                String name = patient.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                                String description = patient.child("description").getValue(String.class);
                                String tokennumber = patient.child("tokennumber").getValue(String.class);
                                String disease = patient.child("disease").getValue(String.class);

                                medicaldetail medi = new medicaldetail(name, description, tokennumber, disease);
                                medical_list.add(medi);

                            }

                            act_adapter obj = new act_adapter(Reports.this, medical_list);
                            listview.setAdapter(obj);
                            obj.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
    `


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/spcZt.png
```

Comment: Have you solved the issue?

Comment: No.please suggest me a query,since im a beginner.

Comment: It will help you if I'll write you some code?

Comment: yes of course..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem in your code is that you are missing a child in your query and for that, please change the following line of code:

```
Query query = reference.child("patient").orderByChild("dates").equalTo(date);
```

to:

```
Query query = reference.child("patient").child(patientId).orderByChild("dates").equalTo(date);
```

In which `patientId` is the id of the patient that you are looking for to meet condition. For example could be: `9876543210`.

**Edit:**

According to your comment, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference patientRef = rootRef.child("patient");

ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
            String mobileNumber = ds.getKey();

            DatabaseReference mobileNumberRef = patientRef.child("mobileNumber");
            Query query = mobileNumberRef.orderByChild("dates").equalTo(date);
            ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for(DataSnapshot dSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String name = dSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                        Log.d("TAG", name);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
            };
            query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
patientRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener);
```

Comment: i think you are not getting my point.i want to go through all mobile numbers and get the data only  which meets the date.i mean not only for 9876543210 and also 9876543211,..etc

Comment: I understood now. So pelase see my updated answer. It does work now?

Comment: thanks for your work.but while debug; it jumps to ValueEventListener valueEventListener = new ValueEventListener() to patientRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(valueEventListener); and anyway im not getting string value.pls help

Comment: no.there is no error but it just jumps to that line as i told previously.thanks fr your response

Comment: If you are trying to use the following line `Log.d("TAG", mobileNumber);` right after `String mobileNumber = ds.getKey();` what is the result?

Comment: Thankyou so much.im getting value after changing "mobileNumber" to mobileNumber in this line. DatabaseReference mobileNumberRef = patientRef.child("mobileNumber"); but im getting only one data.whether i need to put another for loop to get others? if so please tell me where to put.thanks.

Comment: If you query after a specific number and only one number is in the database, then you'll get only one result. If you want other result, then you need to change your query accordingly.

Comment: i want to go through all mobilenumbers and retrieve the datas which meets the given date.so what change i have to do in above your code?

Comment: There are a few of changes but in order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you. Please also don't forget to add a screenshot of your real database to see it more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

change your query like this ..

```
Query query = reference.child("patient").child("9876543210").child(databasereferenceobject.getKey()).orderByChild("date").equalTo(date);
```

Comment: not only for the child "9876543210".and also for "9876543211",..etc.i want to search through all mobile numbers and want the data only which meets the condition "date".

Comment: then remove this code try it child("9876543210").child(databasereferenceobject.getKey()).